# Inside a textarea: catch if user is pressing enter on an empty line

Tags: jquery, keydown

I know this is kind of an odd question, but: Inside a textarea, how can I know if the user is pressing enter (e.keycode==13) **on an empty line** on the keydown event?

I have to trigger a specific sync function everytime the user presses enter *except* if the user is just adding new lines for fun (calling the sync function in those cases, would be a terrible waste of resources).

Comment: the sync function must only be triggered if the user presses enter on a line that contains at least 1 character. the user can get to an empty line be pressing enter twice for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution!

```
$('#q').keydown(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        if($(this).val()) {
            if($(this).val().substr($(this).getCursorPosition()-1,1).length) {
                //sync function here!
            } else {
                //user is pressing enter on empty line
            }
        }
    }
});

new function(a){a.fn.getCursorPosition=function(){var b=0;var c=a(this).get(0);if(document.selection){c.focus();var d=document.selection.createRange();var e=document.selection.createRange().text.length;d.moveStart("character",-c.value.length);b=d.text.length-e}else if(c.selectionStart||c.selectionStart=="0")b=c.selectionStart;return b}}(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends on how they got there in the first place.  If the user presses enter on a full line does the sync function get called? If so, then how do they ever get to an empty line?

Comment: the sync function must only be triggered if the user presses enter on a line that contains at least 1 character. the user can get to an empty line be pressing enter twice for example.

Comment: It seems to me that the user would only be able to have multiple lines from your example if they made a lot of empty lines before typing anything at all.  If the user is halfway through a line of text and presses enter, do they go to a new line?  Do they post their total text by pressing enter ever, or is it only by clicking a button?

Comment: the sync function gets triggered by simply pressing enter (or the submit button, whatever happens first). some users play arround with the enter and i want to avoid those extra calls.